# Simply AngularJS or MEAN stack for my web app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm learning AngularJS and the MEAN stack, and I'm currently building a simple application that would render data retrieved from an API.

My question is this:
Do I need a full stack (like MEAN) for my webapp if my application is only going to request data from an API, say Google Maps API for instance. Would AngularJS be enough? Or do I need the Node.js and MongoDB component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the back-end functionality is coming from third-party APIs, the minimum you need from the MEAN stack is AngularJS, like you've said. That would enable you to create a client-side application and that could well be enough to meet your requirements.

You'd need to run this on a server somewhere. If you didn't have a web server but you did have a general 'compute' server available, you could run Node.js on there to serve up your application. Other web servers are available.

You can run AngularJS directly on top of Node.js. That said, if you wanted a middleware layer to help translate between the two and/or provide extra functionalty, Express.js can do that. Express only works on Node.js so you wouldn't be able to use this if you went with a different web server but there's alternative technologies that you could use instead.

Finally, if you needed to persist data that's been retrieved from this API, you could store it in MongoDB. From what you've said, this probably isn't required but is something to bear in mind.

In short, if you're application is powered by this API, you probably only need a front-end. A site using AngularJS and somewhere to run it should be all you need.